# Rotation of people for an assessment event

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the rotation of people for an assessment event. We have 4 groups of students- 6 each. On the other hand we have 4 groups of assessors- 2 groups x 6 people, 1 group x 3 people, 1 group x 4 people. The number of assessors is non-negotiable as it was based on the number of students they will be assessing. The assessment takes 4 rounds of activities taking place in parallel. Until now, all the assessors were assigned to a specific assessment and did not rotate, whilst all the candidates (in their groups) rotated through the exercises (please see current set-up below) . **Can you **please help me figure out a way how to rotate the assessors through the exercises as well**?** Thank you so much!

Current Set-Up:

```
  Round 1           Round 2           Round 3           Round 4
```

Ex.1: Candidate Group 1 Candidate Group 2 Candidate Group 3 Candidate Group 4 
      Assessors 1-6   Assessors 1-6       Assessors 1-6     Assessors 1-6

Ex.2: Candidate Group 4 Candidate Group 1 Candidate Group 2 Candidate Group 3 
      Assessors 7-12  Assessors 7-12      Assessors 7-12    Assessors 7-12

Ex.3: Candidate Group 3 Candidate Group 4 Candidate Group 1 Candidate Group 2 
      Assessors 13-16   Assessors 13-16   Assessors 13-16   Assessors 13-16

Ex.4: Candidate Group 2 Candidate Group 3 Candidate Group 4 Candidate Group 1 
      Assessors 17-19   Assessors 17-19   Assessors 17-19   Assessors 17-19

Comment: What are the requirements for the rotation? Or, why isn't the one you wrote good?
Also, the table is quite tricky to read as it is now.

Comment: @MattiP. Hi! Sorry for the table. Formatting must have changed while posting. There is nothing wrong with the one I have outlined above, but Assessors do not rotate. I would like them to rotate through the exercises as well, so they will be able to get a better overview of a candidate.